# WPF setting button cursor to busy what does it exactly mean

Tags: wpf, button, cursor

I would like to set the cursor to busy status when the button is clicked. In a Winform i would have changed the cursor in the click event and revert back after the click logic is executed.  Now reading through few posts about Cursor in WPF , i just want to make sure if Setting the cursor property of the button (its in a UserControl) through xaml means -> show the cursor when the button is clicked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the cursor property in XAML will change the Cursor everytime your mouse moves over it. What you want is `Mouse.OverrideCursor` to `Cursors.Wait`, but you have to do it in your code, not xaml. Which makes sense, if you want a wait cursor, your xaml usually don't know when your operation is finished, because you have to reset it to the previous state or clear it. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307004/changing-the-cursor-in-wpf-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt) for further info.

Comment: Thanks! actually i read his question and got confused as he says it worked as expected in a Usercontrol but not in a WPF Page!