# Override wait cursor in WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouse-cursor

In a WPF app, we try to hide the mouse cursor by setting

```
<Window Cursor="None" ...>
    ...
</Window>
```

This works fine, for all controls within that window the cursor is not shown. However, while a long-running operation is in progress, the cursor re-appears combined with the typical Windows 7 progress wheel:

[image]

Does anybody know how we can get rid of that wait cursor? (A lot of similar questions have been asked, but it seems everyone tries to do it the other way round and *show* the wait cursor while we're trying to *hide* it...)

Comment: Does it appear when your application is (Not responding)?

Comment: Maybe this answer help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307004/changing-the-cursor-in-wpf-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Try using the OverrideCursor property which will override the cursor for the whole application.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. Now, when clicking a button that performs a longer operation, the default cursor is shown shortly, followed by the wait cursor.